# Need help installing the UDP package in TCL

Tags: udp, tcl, tcltk

My end goal is to have UDP support in TCL on windows, using either ActiveState or some other version of TCL. From what I can see, and read - the UDP package should be installed via "teacup"

Instructions I find are old, out of date, etc. Google is not helping because it is only finding old documents.

1) The current version of activestate tcl does not include teacup -

2) I can't seem to figure out how to install teacup it from GIT ...

3) If I should use a different TCL - that's fine - I welcome suggestions.

Suggestions?

Edit - === Part2 === Backed to 8.5 ===

Teacup is present, I can install udp, but it will not load.
No idea how to determine if I need another library or something.
suggestions?

[image: Screen shot - showing load issues]

Comment: Did you try to obtain a tclkit incl. TclUDP, e.g., from https://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator?

Comment: Policies prevent that- but if I go back to TCL 8.5 - teacup is present and I can install but that does not work

Comment: You should then tell your company that 8.5 is end of life, so that policy should get updated quickly! In any case, you can also obtain a tclkit with 8.5 and TclUDP from that site (just pick a patch release).

Comment: Tcl 8.6 active state is ONLY - 64bit, the DLL is 32bit. Discussions with IT departments that are security minded are very hard sometimes.

Comment: Well, then get a tclkit amd64 with 8.6, extract the TclUDP library from it, and use that with your ActiveTcl 8.6 installation. Use `sdx unwrap` on the tclkit, see https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/sdx (you need to get sdx first).

Answer (score 0):

Solution was this:

1. Do not use ActiveState TCL 8.6, use ActiveState TCL8.5 32bit.

   REASON: 64bit might work for you but - 64bit did not for me.
2. Use `teacup install udp`

   the teacup.exe is next to the tclsh.exe file in c:\tcl\bin
3. Go find the "udp1011.dll" file in the teapot directory.
4. Copy that file to the TCLSH.exe directory

Then, examples from https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TclUDP
appear to work